# Zuul route from root path

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have some microservices discovered with Eureka. Most of them provide some API.
And I have "edge" service called "Gateway service" which is Zuul Proxy actually.
The thing is that there is a web application. It was hosted by gateway service for a long time and there was not any problem with that.
But right now I need to host this client on separate service behind gateway.
It's not a problem. I created new service and put web application there. But the thing is that Zuul on gateway service have next configuration

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  prefix: /api
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie, Set-Cookie
  routes:
    config-service:
      path: /conf/**
      serviceId: config-service
    security-service:
      path: /security/**
      serviceId: security-service
      stripPrefix: false
    request-service:
      path: /requests/**
      stripPrefix: false
```

I need to do so that user able to access web application from a root path like this `http://app.com/`.
But right now I can access it only by `http://app.com/api/` which is completely incorrect.

My task is:

1. Make web app hosted on another service available from root path.
2. It also very important that `/api` prefix remain for all other services.

I tried to implement `ZuulFilter`. But looks like it does nothing with root path and runs only when there is match with any routes described above.

How can I make this work?

**UPDATE**: I have a little success with `ZuulFilter`. I made it work. Here is configuration of Zuul:

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie, Set-Cookie
  routes:
    api: /api/**
    config-service:
      path: /conf/**
      serviceId: config-service
    security-service:
      path: /security/**
      serviceId: security-service
      stripPrefix: false
    request-service:
      path: /requests/**
      stripPrefix: false
    frontend-host-service:
      path: /**
```

And `ZuulFilter` itself

```
@Bean
    public ZuulFilter apiPrefixStrip(RouteLocator routeLocator) {
        return new ZuulFilter() {

            @Override
            public String filterType() {
                return "pre";
            }

            @Override
            public int filterOrder() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldFilter() {
                RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
                return context.getRequest().getRequestURI().startsWith("/api");
            }

            @Override
            public Object run() {
                RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
                String path = context.getRequest().getRequestURI();
                Route route = routeLocator.getMatchingRoute(path.substring(4));
                if (route != null) {
                    context.put("proxy",route.getId());
                    context.put("requestURI", route.getPath());
                    context.set("serviceId", route.getLocation());
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

How this work:
there is property `zuul.routes.api=/api/**` which does not do anything actually. It just allows to map all matched paths to Zuul filter chain ([described in documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR3/#_plain_embedded_zuul)). All other routes described here is set like there is no `/api` at all. It allows to reach services like this: `http://app.com/requests` e.g. for request service.
The `ZuulFilter` performs check for every request described in properties but it runs only if the requested URI starts with `/api` and it redirects this request same way like there is no any `/api` in path.

It works really. But I still dont like this solution because there are endpoints without `/api` prefix still remain on gateway service. May be anybody knows how to improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. Drop the `zuul.prefix` property.
2. Prepend the prefix of 'api`to all of your`zuul.routes.*.path` properties.
3. Add a final route (to the end of the list) that has the following properties:

---

```
app:
  path: /**
  stripPrefix: false
```

(3) is very important as the order of the routes here matters.  This is the order that incoming requests will evaluate whether or not a route matches.  It is also important that you do this in yaml, as order will be preserved, where it might not be with a properties file (according to the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html)).

Comment: Thank you for an answer. This kind of solution I was thinking first. And I am completely sure this will work. But I think that writing ```/api``` prefix  explicitly for each route is a little confusing. Mostly because the configuration I posted actually contains 50+ routes, so it is not suit enough for my situation :) This detail I forgot to mention, my bad. But this will be good enough for proxies with a few routes.

Comment: You might have to most/all of the 50+ routes, but it will clearly suggest what the exact route is for each service and it is a very flexible solution for supporting your other services that are not yet prefixed with `/api`.